Proof that a Function is Uniformly Continuous
Let A and B be intervals. Suppose we have two uniformly continuous functions $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:B\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in{A\cap{B}}$, $f(x)=g(x)$.  Also suppose that $A\cap{B}$ is non-empty.  Define $h:A\cup{B}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be $f(x)$ if $x\in{A}$ and $g(x)$ if $x\in{B\setminus{A}}$.  Prove $h(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

My Attempt: I know that if the intersection is non-empty then for all points that are in  the intersection $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous . So by epsilon delta definition we  have $$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta_1>0)(\forall{x,y}\in{A})(|x-y|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon),$$ and $$(\exists\delta_2>0)(\forall{x,y}\in{B})(|x-y|<\delta_2\implies|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon).$$ I was thinking maybe I could use these two definitions to show that $h$ is uniformly continuous on the set ${B}$ but from there I really don't know where to go. It seems intuitive to me that this must be true but I just don't know how to connect all the dots. Thanks for any help.

One strategy is through by sequences. Try to prove that  for each pair of sequences $(x_{n}){n \in \mathbb{N}} $ and $(y{n}){n \in \mathbb{N}} $ such that $\lim{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_{n}-y_{n}) = 0 $ that this implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(h(x_{n})-h(y_{n})) = 0 $. If in your question you had the hypothesis that $A\cup B$ is a compact set, then it would work.

The conclusion does not hold. Some additional assumptions are necessary. For example $A$ and $B$ are intervals.
Consider $A=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ and $B=(0,1)\cup (2,3).$ Let $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x\in (2,3).$ Both functions are uniformly continuous. However $h$ is not uniformly continuous as $h(2-\delta)=0$ and $h(2 +\delta)=1$ for $0<\delta<1.$
Assume $A$ and $B$ are intervals. It suffices to restrict to the case $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A.$ Consider the sets $I_1=A\setminus B,$ $I_2=B\setminus A$ and $I_3=A\cap B.$  Then $I_1\neq\emptyset$ and $I_2\neq\emptyset .$ Moreover $I_1,I_2$ and $I_3$ are disjoint intervals. The interval $I_3$ (possibly a single point) is located between $I_1$ and $I_2.$ Let $c\in I_3.$  For given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0,$ such that if $x,y\in A$ or $x,y\in B$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|h(x)-h(y)|<\varepsilon/2.$ Let $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x\in I_1,$ $y\in I_2.$ Then $|x-c|<\delta$ and $|y-c|<\delta,$ as  $c$ is located between $x$ and $y.$  Thus $$|h(x)-h(y)|\le |h(x)-h(c)|+ |h(c)-h(y)|<\varepsilon$$

I meant to add A and B are intervals in the question, I just made a mistake.

It is inconvenient answering questions which are modified after the answers are posted.

I understand, the correct question is posted. There will be no more edits.

You were on the right path. Let us take an arbitrary $\epsilon> 0$. Because of the uniform continuity of $f$ on $A$ and $g$ on $B$, we have:
$$\exists \delta_1>0, \forall x, y \in A, \left |x-y \right | < \delta_1\implies \left |f(x)-f(y)\right | <\epsilon\\
\exists \delta_2>0, \forall x, y \in B, \left |x-y \right | < \delta_2\implies \left |g(x)-g(y)\right | <\epsilon$$
As $A$ and $B$ are intervals, $A\cap B$ is also an interval.

If it is not reduced to a point, it has a size (max bound - min bound) $sz>0$.
Let us now take $\delta = min(\delta_1, \delta_2, sz/2)$. Let us finally considere $x, y \in A\cup B$ verifying $\left|x-y\right |<\delta$. As $\delta < sz$, both $x$ and $y$ must be simultaneously element of $A$ or $B$ (if $x \in A \setminus B$ and $y \in B\setminus A$, then $\left | x-y\right | >= sz$).
If $x, y \in A$, then $\left |h(x)-h(y)\right | = \left |f(x)-f(y)\right | < \epsilon$, because $\left | x - y \right | < \delta <= \delta_1$
If $x, y \in B$, then $\left |h(x)-h(y)\right | = \left |g(x)-g(y)\right | < \epsilon$, because $\left | x - y \right | < \delta <= \delta_2$

If $A\cap B$ is reduced to a point, let us say $A\cap B = \left \lbrace c \right \rbrace$, $c$ is an interval bound for both $A$ and $B$ and we can assume that elements of $A$ are smaller than (or equal to) $c$ and that elements of $B$ are greater than (or equal to) $c$. If it is the opposite, we can just exchange $A$ and $B$ in what follows. As $\epsilon>0$ we know $\frac\epsilon 2>0$ and we have:
$$\exists \delta_{1}'>0, \forall x, y \in A, \left |x-y \right | < \delta_{1}'\implies \left |f(x)-f(y)\right | <\frac\epsilon 2\\
\exists \delta_{2}'>0, \forall x, y \in B, \left |x-y \right | < \delta_{2}'\implies \left |g(x)-g(y)\right | <\frac\epsilon 2$$
Let us use $\delta = min(\delta_{1}', \delta_{2}')$. Let us finally considere $x, y \in A\cup B$ verifying $\left|x-y\right |<\delta$.
If $x, y \in A$, then $\left |h(x)-h(y)\right | = \left |f(x)-f(y)\right | < \frac\epsilon 2<\epsilon$, because $\left | x - y \right | < \delta <= \delta_{1}'$
If $x, y \in B$, then $\left |h(x)-h(y)\right | = \left |g(x)-g(y)\right | < \frac\epsilon 2<\epsilon$, because $\left | x - y \right | < \delta <= \delta_{2}'$
Else one is element of $A$ and the other of $B$. We can assume $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. If it is the opposite, we can just exchange $x$ and $y$. We now have $x\le c\le y$ and $y - x< \delta$, hence $c-x<\delta$ and $y-c<\delta$. Finally:


$$\begin{aligned}\left |h(x)-h(y)\right |&\le \left |h(x)-h(c)\right | + \left |h(c)-h(y)\right | = \left |f(x)-f(c)\right | + \left |g(c)-g(y)\right |\\
&\le \frac\epsilon 2 + \frac\epsilon 2\\&\le \epsilon\end{aligned}$$
So for any $\epsilon >0$ we could exhibit a $\delta > 0$ verifying $\forall x, y\in A\cup B, \left |x-y \right | < \delta\implies \left |h(x)-h(y)\right | <\epsilon$. Which is the definition of the absolute continuity of $h$ on $A\cup B$.

It may occur that $sz=0,$ as $A\cap B$ can be a single point set.

@RyszardSzwarc: You are right of course... Post edited.

Uniform continuity can be characterized in terms of the relation of infinite proximity $\approx$ as follows: whenever points $x,y$ in the domain satisfy $x\approx y$, one also has $f(x)\approx f(y)$.  If $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, we use the fact that a uniformly continuous function extends by continuity to the shadow (standard part) $c=\text{st}(x)$.  Then the $h(x)\approx h(c)\approx h(y)$ and therefore the extended function is uniformly continuous.
